# How do I use ReadString in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, irvine32, masm32

```
mov  edx,offset Prompt1     
call WriteString

mov  ecx,32     
mov  edx,offset String1     
call ReadString
```

Now, how do I go about accessing `String1`? How do I move it into a register so I can do shifting operations on it?

For example,

```
mov eax, edx
shr eax, 1
```

The problem that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to access `String1`. It doesn't seem to be going into the eax register, but if I call `WriteString` it will appear, so I believe it is in EDX.

Comment: Irvine32 functions have documentation, google it and read it.  e.g. http://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm

Comment: related: [Reversing and changing case of a given string x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55992974) quotes the manual for other details of how to use it, like how big a buffer you need.

Answer (score 4):

The data is read into memory starting at the address of `String1`. There is a null byte (0) after the last input character.

So if after your `call ReadString`, you write `mov edx,offset String1`, then EDX is pointing to the first character of the string.

You can then process the string. For example, to add 1 to each character:

```
    call ReadString
    mov edx,offset String1
theLoop:
    mov al,[edx]
    cmp al,0
    jz done    ; the character is 0, so done
    inc al
    mov [edx],al
    inc edx    ; next character
    jmp theLoop
done:
```

So if the input was "0123abc", that would change the string to "1234bdc".

(for the nitpickers: Yes, I know this could be optimized. In particular the `cmp al,0`. But it's better for beginners to think of comparing ... we can work on optimizations after they have a firm grasp of working at the processor level.)

Comment: Irvine32 functions use a custom calling convention that doesn't clobber any registers, except the return value if there is one.  So `edx` will still be holding the pointer you passed.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadString` requires the buffer address and the size placed in EDX and ECX respectively. So you have to ensure both registers have the necessary information before referring to it. You can do this by storing those values in your data sections, although the size usually only needs to be an assemble-time constant, not actually stored in memory in .data.

So before calling `ReadString`, you have to set up both args

```
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET String1     ; pointer
    MOV     ECX, SIZEOF String1 - 1 ; max byte count, not including terminating 0
    call    ReadString
 ; EAX return value = number of bytes actually read
 ; no other registers modified in Irvine32's unusual calling convention
```

Online docs for Irvine32:
https://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm

> Reads a string of up to ECX non-null characters from standard input, stopping when the user presses the Enter key.
> A null byte is stored following the characters input, but the trailing carriage return and line feed characters are not placed into the buffer.
> ECX should always be smaller than the buffer size (never equal to the buffer size) because the null byte could be the (ECX+1)th character stored.

The docs also have a similar example to this, showing reserving a buffer as well.

Comment: `MOV     ECX, SIZEOF String1` is wrong, that would put the terminating `0` byte past the end of the array if the user entered that many characters or more.  I fixed that for you and linked the docs, which is probably a good thing to have in an answer on a question with this title.

Answer (score -1):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data


buffer BYTE 21 DUP(0)
byteCount DWORD ? 


.code
main PROC

mov   edx, OFFSET buffer
mov   ecx, SIZEOF buffer
call  ReadString
mov   byteCount, eax


call writestring


exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.